# How to view previous inputted MAC Address for WiFi network

Tags: terminal, network, wifi, internet, mac-address

I have a Belkin Router and accidentally changed the MAC Address for the Wireless Area Network. Is there a way to retrieve previous inputted MAC Address using Terminal?

I'm looking around system and network logs but I can't find previous records of MAC Address for my WiFi network.

Comment: Which MAC address did you change and where?

Comment: If you would like your question to be of a great help to others, I advise you to make clearer which MAC address you changed (there are many MAC involved in the simplest network with a router and a Mac).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information should be printed on a label located on your router. Find the one that corresponds to your wireless networking `(LAN/WLAN)`. If you can't find it, you can follow the instructions here to reset your router to factory defaults:

Method 1:

> ```
> 1. Type http://192.168.2.1 in your browser, then restore factory defaults
> ```

Method 2:

> ```
> 2. Hold the `Reset` button on the back/bottom/side of the unit pressed
>    for 10+ seconds, while the unit is powered on
> ```

[image: Belkin Router Sticker]

> [belkin reset instructions here](http://en-us-support.belkin.com/app/answers/page/a_id/8436)

Answer (score 0):

I think by restarting your machine its MAC address will restore to its original value. If not you can get your hardcoded MAC address by executing this command in the terminal:

`networksetup -getmacaddress [your network interface, e.g. en1]`

Comment: This command, as the standard `ifconfig en1`, will display the actual MAC address.